# Jquery: Animate to Center of Another Object

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to builder a nav slider, which is like an arrow sliding under the navigation links. I would like to animate it to the center of a div.

This is my nav code:

```
<nav>

        <ul class="tabs">
            <li id="tab1"><a href="#">Cursussen</a></li>
            <li id="tab2"><a href="#">Resultaten</a></li>
            <li id="tab3"><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li id="tab4"><a href="#">Profiel</a></li>
            <li id="tab5"><a href="#">Aanbod</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a id='slider'><img src="img/arrow.png"></a>

</nav>
```

And this is the jquery i use to animate:

```
$(function(){
        $('li#tab1').click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $('#slider').animate({
                left : '32'
            });
        });
});
```

I was thinking I could create a var like the following, which calculates the width of the div I want to move to the center of. But I don't exactly know how to write the code for the animation part.

```
var w = '$(#slider).parent().width()'/2
```

Comment: `var w = parseInt($('#slider').parent().width(),10)/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4efa/2/

In particular, I used the following method:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var ulOffsetLeft = $('ul.tabs').offset().left;
    var currentOffset = $(this).offset().left;

    var delta = currentOffset - ulOffsetLeft;

    $('#slider').clearQueue().animate({'margin-left': delta});

});​
```

UPDATE: I added some automatic padding calculation to this new fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vt2dv/8/

Comment: Thanks for you awnser! Though i can't seem to make it work. The sliderarrow is there, but it doesn't move at all. Is there something i'm missing?

btw: i'm kinda new to creating my own code. What i usually did was edit code that other people created.

Comment: Did you click the lower JS fiddle link? If so, did you make sure to click on 'Run' in the top-left corner? Or are you talking about code you copied?

Comment: I tried to copy your code into my files. But couldn't figure out why it didn't work. It worked before, but only if i give up a number for animate left. I want it to work automaticly.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of my code as i created it. Including a jquery plugin for the 'tabs' i use. I haven't integraded your code into this. What i did when i tested it, was remove my function and replace it with yours. (http://jsfiddle.net/v7dH3/) I probarbly did something wrong. Might be something really simple, but i can't see what it is..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v7dH3/1/ that one seems to be sliding. Your CSS configuration was weird.